# Navigate to page and open details element via id with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a monthly calendar view (events-calendar.html) and when the user clicks on a particular date on that page, as an example April 15th, I want the anchor tag to navigate to (events-day.html) and open (details id="april15").

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Send**

```
<a href='components/bydate.html?view=apr15'>
Apr 15
</a>
```

**Get**

```
window.location.search.substr(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Dinesh,  I added the anchor tag as you suggested onto the div on the calendar, where do I add the (window.location.search.substr(1)) code?

Comment: In event-day.html 's javascript as per your wish...

Comment: I added a script as follows window.location.search.substr(1) but I get the following error message  Cannot GET /components/bydate.html

Comment: its a basic problem not bound to the question you have asked.